# Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'UInt'

Tags: swift2, xcode10

```
func loadRequest() {
    var url : URL
    if (self.url?.hasPrefix(localPrefix) == true) {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        if let port = appDelegate.webserver.port {
            let startIndex = self.url?.characters.index((self.url?.startIndex)!, offsetBy: localPrefix.characters.count)
            let endIndex = self.url?.range(of: "/", options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range: startIndex! ..< (self.url?.endIndex)!)
            let strURL = localPrefix + String(describing: port) + (self.url?.substring(from: (endIndex?.lowerBound)!))!
            url = URL(string: strURL)!
        } else {
            return
        }
    } else if (self.url?.hasPrefix("http") == true) {
        url = URL(string: self.url!)!
    } else {
        url = URL(string: self.url!)!
    }

    print("Loading URL: \(url.absoluteString)")
    let request = URLRequest(url: url, cachePolicy: NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 10)

    webView!.load(request)
}
```

The error line for above part

```
if let port = appDelegate.webserver.port {
```

error>>Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'UInt'

How to solve this??

Comment: What is the type of `appDelegate.webserver.port`? If it's an unsigned integer like the compiler says, the fix is easy. Replace the `if let` with a simple `let`. Only use the `if let` statement if the constant is an optional value.

Comment: yeah.. remove the 'if' statement then no error more.